# Can VSCode do intellisense when using an external JS script of an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I have an HTML page and in that page I have given some elements IDs and I've defined CSS classes and some elements use those classes.

If I load that page in a browser the web dev tools will show those elements and offer code assistance.

I have created a JavaScript file that I am including in my HTML page.

Can VSCode give me intelligent information when I write code in the external JavaScript file in a similar way to the web devs tool does or a node js project does?

Actually, does VSCode do intellisense if the JavaScript *IS* embedded in the HTML page (this question answered below)?

**UPDATE:**
I did a test with JavaScript inline in an HTML page and vscode did not show the element in the code complete list or any awareness of it:

[image]

It only showed code intelligence with code from other script blocks.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
It looks like theres a few parts to this.

There's no awareness of HTML elements, as shown and discovered in web tools in the browser.
There's no awareness of other Javascript libraries in the inline script.
So there's probably no awareness of HTML elements in an external JS and no awareness of JS objects from the main HTML page either.

Comment: This article might help: https://www.roboleary.net/2020/12/28/vscode-intellisense-external-library.html

Comment: It's unusual these days to write html as you do on screenshots. Usually modules are used which correctly hint variables

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26338

Comment: @Konrad That's true. There are cases for vanilla Javascript. Even inline, there is no awareness of HTML elements in the page or CSS classes.

Comment: @Konrad Would converting this to a module fix it?